# Unable to write to file in message handler

Tags: node.js, fs, discord.js

I am coding a Discord bot that can write to a local text file on [glitch.com](http://glitch.com).

When I use the `ready` event handler my program is able to write to the file just fine:

```
client.on('ready', () => {
  fs.appendFile('./log.txt', 'Hello\n', (err) => {
    if(err) throw err;
  });
});
//Writes to file
```

However, when I try to write to the same file using the `message` event handler, nothing happens:

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
  fs.appendFile('./log.txt', 'Hello\n', (err) => {
    if(err) throw err;
  });
});
//Does not write to file
```

Do I need to change permissions on this file? Or change it from a local file? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this might work, I don't have time to test it but it's using the [writeFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) method as opposed to the [appendFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback) method

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
 fs.writeFile('./log.txt', message, (err) => {
     if(err) throw err;
  });
});
```

Assuming you already have your local text file you wouldn't need to make a new one. So you may as well use `writeFile()`, only thing I can see going wrong with this is it may refresh the file every message, but you could probably fix that with a message collector that updates the file every say 100 messages.

Comment: you might want to do `message+'\n'` so that the messages will go line by line

Answer (score 0):

Using `appendFileSync` instead of `appendFile` should fix your issue, as `appendFileSync` is more reliable and has less of a chance to create errors. Good luck!

Comment: Nothing changes.

Comment: Might have something to do with Glitch.com itself; you should try this locally on your computer to check if it works there.

Comment: Well it does write after I refresh the app. How can I make it so I don't have to make it refresh to show the writes?

Comment: Once again, it might have something to just do with how **Glitch.com** operates the code; I have tried this code on my end (locally on my PC) and it works completely fine when a message is received.